# Creating a mean value function, returning error message about NAs

Tags: r, csv, mean

I am trying to write a function that will return a mean of a columns across multiple .csv files. However, the function seems to be stuck with my mean calculation, as it returns `NA` values:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
  dy <- list.files("specdata", full.names = T)
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in id){
    rbind(df,read.csv(dy[i]))
  }
  if(pollutant == "nitrate"){mean(df$nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)} 
  if(pollutant == "sulfate"){mean(df$sulfate, na.rm = TRUE)}
}
```

Suggestions on resolving this issue greatly appreciated.

Comment: You surely can find useful links here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[r]%20pollutantmean

Comment: I believe the default behavior of read.csv is to ignore the header. If it's not getting the names, then it won't know what df$nitrate is. Maybe try adding `header = T` to the read.csv part?

Comment: @goodtimeslim  It does get the `header`.  `head(read.csv('001.csv'),2)
#        Date sulfate nitrate ID
1 2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
2 2003-01-02      NA      NA  1`

Comment: I think you need `df <- rbind(df,read.csv(dy[i]))` in the for loop and the `return` in the return(mean(df$nitrate...`

Comment: Tried the function using the `spec` folder after fixing..  `pollutantmean('nitrate', 1:2)#[1] 0.9038795; df1 <- read.csv('001.csv');  df2 <- read.csv('002.csv');
 dfN <- rbind(df1,df2);
 mean(dfN$nitrate, na.rm=TRUE)#[1] 0.9038795` .  In the `pollutantmean` function I didn't use the directory as I was using spec folder as the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly returning the mean values from your custom function like this:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
    dy <- list.files("specdata", full.names=TRUE)
    df <- data.frame()
    for (i in id) {
        df <- rbind(df, read.csv(dy[i]))
    }
    if(pollutant == "nitrate") { return(mean(df$nitrate, na.rm=TRUE)) }
    if(pollutant == "sulfate") { return(mean(df$sulfate, na.rm=TRUE)) }
}
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, then you likely have data frame columns which contain character data, causing `R` to give you `NA` values.  Insert these two lines in the `pollutantmean` function to see whether you are dealing with numeric columns:

```
print(class(df$nitrate))
print(class(df$sulfate))
```

If you see "factor", or anything other than numeric, then you will know that your input data contains something other than pure numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the catch...I missed that ^ ^